# how to prevent onChange from triggered when key is pressed

Tags: javascript

Im pretty new to Javascript.
I have a customised drop-down list, on which there are 2 event listeners
onKeyDown and onChange.

1. Mouse events trigger onChange
2. Key events trigger onKeyDown and also onChange

   On key events I want to avoid onKeyDown from being triggered.
   I did try to cancelBubble on the keyDown it did not work.Just on one key press the list disappears.

   I did try to cancelBubble on KeyUp, but onChange is called before that.

   How can I do this?
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Include your code in the question

Comment: Due to confidentiality I would not be able to copy the source code here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just change the value of those listeners when your state change happens?

```
document.getElementById('myCustomDropdown').onchange = "";
```